# Rigging mechanical rods

Tags: animation, rigging

I'm new to rigging process and I can't solve my problem. I'm trying to create armature on this mechanical arm but there are a lot of constraints (for my experience) How can I rotate multiple rods with different pivot?

Thanks a lot if someone can help me

[image]

Comment: hello, maybe show the different positions the arm can get, etc

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is a terible explanation. So sorry for that.
My problem is bind block A to the movement of four different rods.
The pivots are yellow dots.